# MySQL select value in range where that value not in another range

Tags: mysql, subquery, notin

We have a table where we log every customer request, each request get's a `created_at` and `customer_email` column.

```
mysql> select * from requests;

+---------------------+-----------------------+
| created_at          | customer_email        |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2016-08-08 14:05:50 | user1@example.com     |
| 2016-08-08 14:05:51 | user2@example.com     |
| 2017-08-15 14:41:40 | user3@example.com     |
| 2017-08-15 15:17:25 | user2@example.com     |
| 2018-08-15 15:30:41 | user1@example.com     |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm trying to get records for `customer email` that was `created_at` in 08/2018 but didn't create a request before that. In other words, find out what customers that created requests in 08/2018 are new customers.
Here's the query i'm trying and it's returning 0

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_email
FROM
    requests
WHERE
    created_at > '2018-08-01'
        AND customer_email NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            customer_email
        FROM
            requests
        WHERE
            created_at < '2018-08-01')
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The query looks fine. Did you find any email manually which was newly created?

Comment: it returns no results even though i know I have some new ones in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause.

Using [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp) function, we can find out the `first_created_at` for a `customer_email`, and then utilizing [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause, we restrict our result set to the ones having `first_created_at` after **08/18**.

```
SELECT customer_email, DATE(MIN(created_at)) AS first_created_at 
FROM requests
GROUP BY customer_email 
HAVING first_created_at >= DATE('2018-08-01')
```